# Run rspec with format options only on rake task

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to use instafail only when running `rake`. For the moment my Rakefile looks like this ( :

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)
require 'rake'
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'

RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec) do |t|
  t.rspec_opts = '--require rspec/instafail --format RSpec::Instafail'
end

Rails.application.load_tasks
```

And in my `lib/task/default` :

```
task default: ["spec", "test"]
```

But it fails, instafail is used but the task "test" is not called anymore.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it fails"? Is it raising an exception or running your tests with the default formatter? If it's the former, can you update your question with a stack trace?

Comment: It using the default formater.

Comment: Hmm, I can't recreate that. What version of RSpec are you using?

Comment: Rspec 3.3.2. Can I edit separately the `spec` task ?

Comment: You can always define your own `spec` task. The RSpec default task basically just shells out. Try creating a new task and use this line to call rspec `system "rspec --require rspec/instafail --format RSpec::Instafail"`

Comment: it works with a `lib/tasks/spec.rake` with the code you gave me. It's really curious that the code below doesn't work.

Comment: It's blocking all my rake commands... :/

Comment: @Johnson I've edited the question.